# how to prevent dojo name text box remove/delete name onclick

Tags: dojo, xpages

I want prevent users from possibility to delete a name by accident from the list.. It should be possible to delete a name by clicking only on [x]...

[image: Dojo Name Text Box]

Thanks

Comment: You need to supply more details: how is it behaving now, how should it behave, what code did you try, where did you get stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to reconsider that plan :-) - the behavior of the dojo value picker in any other application is to make the full entry a click target - since you don't control other applications, you create an interaction inconsistency that will rather annoy users.

... But if you have to:

The Dojo UI interaction is deeply wired into that control and can't be changed easily. Your sensible option is to take the source of the control and create your own dojo/dijiit widget. Since dojo supports name spaces, that can coexist with the default control. Check the dojo documentation. It contains tutorials how to do that.

You might find there are better uses for your time.

Comment: Thank you... I think it much easier to tell my manager that it's "as designed" behavior..

Answer (score 1):

Reconsider the plan as Stephan says. My advice: you have used [filter](http://infolib.lotus.com/resources/oneui/3.0/docPublic/components/filters.htm) elements from OneUI framework. That's not a good choice in my opinion.

My suggestion is to use [list](http://infolib.lotus.com/resources/oneui/3.0/docPublic/components/lists.htm) element of OneUI instead, for example:
[image]